# Compile Boost.Regex 1.76 in NON C++03 mode with MSVC _MANAGED (C++/CLI)?

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, boost-regex

**TL;DR**

Is it possible to compile Boost.Regex 1.76 in Header Only Mode (*non* `BOOST_REGEX_CXX03` mode) with a C++/CLI i.e. `/clr` i.e. `_MANAGED` project?

---

We have been using [Boost.Regex](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html) for years in our regular Visual C++ projects. A very few of our projects are compiled with `Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)` which enables [C++/CLI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI), (and for these we always linked in the boost regex library statically). We always pre-built the boost regex DLL and static lib and then linked these from MSVC.

Now, [with Boost 1.76](https://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_76_0.html) Boost.Regex newly is *header only*, unless compiling in C++03 mode.

> ( Version 1.76.0 ) ...
>
> **Regex:**
>
> - Regex is now header only except in C++03 mode
> - Support for C++03 is now deprecated.
> - ...

However, our C++/CLI project will -- *through the boost config magic* -- automatically select to build Boost.Regex in the C++03 == `BOOST_REGEX_CXX03` mode!

- Our current MSVC is Visual Studio 19.7.6, `_MSC_FULL_VER 192729112`

Since no longer having to pre-build *any* Boost.Regex binaries would be quite handy, we're currently looking into whether we can get the C++/CLI project to compile in the **non** `BOOST_REGEX_CXX03` mode:

- Does anybody know how through the magic of boost/config the macro `BOOST_REGEX_CXX03` is selected for a C++ `_MANAGED` project? (I currently suspect `_CPPLIB_VER`, but I'm not even sure what version that is.)
- Can we switch this? ->

**Is it possible to compile Boost.Regex 1.76 in Header Only Mode with a C++/CLI i.e. `/clr` i.e. `_MANAGED` project?**

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question quickly: **No** it is not possible to compile Boost.Regex in *C++11 mode*, that is *non C++03 mode* with the /clr flag on.

The reason `BOOST_REGEX_CXX03` gets selected under `/clr` is that `boost\regex\config.hpp` will select it if any of `... BOOST_NO_CXX11_HDR_MUTEX ... BOOST_NO_CXX11_HDR_ATOMIC ...` are set, and **these are set under `/clr`** because C++/CLI only supports C++03, or rather it supports all of C++03 whereas e.g. `std::mutex` is not supported in C++/CLI.

As [others have written](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15821942/how-to-implement-a-unmanaged-thread-safe-collection-when-i-get-this-error-mute/15822678#15822678):

> It is not supported because the std::mutex implementation uses
> GetCurrentThreadId(). That's a winapi function that is not *supposed* to
> be use in managed code since it might be running on a custom CLR host
> that doesn't use threads to implement threading.
>
> This is the good kind of problem to have, it shows that you are
> building your code wrong. Your native C++ is being compiled with /clr
> in effect. Which works rather too well, all C++03 compliant code can
> be compiled to MSIL ....

So, IFF you need Boost.regex in a translation unit what is compiled `/clr`, you must use the C++03 mode.

As for the OP problem: Should check whether the given VC++ project that uses C++/CLI really needs to compile all files with /clr on, or maybe the translation units that actually use Boost.Regex are native C++ anyway and could be compiled without /clr and then just linked together with the C++/CLI object files.