# moving a threaded application from c++ to CLR

Tags: multithreading, c++-cli, clr

I have a fairly simple, multithreaded application that runs as a console app in c++, based mostly on calling external dlls. I need to add a Form to it, so I have created a new visual studio project (c++/CLR), and am adding my existing cpp and .h files to it. BUT, when I try to build, i get:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   C1189   #error:  <thread> is not supported when compiling with /clr or /clr:pure.   

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)      #error directive: <mutex> is not supported when compiling with /clr or /clr:pure.
```

IS this how I should be adding a form? How can I get around this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, solved. As here:

[VC2008, how to turn CLR flag off for individual files in C++/CLI project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/808250/vc2008-how-to-turn-clr-flag-off-for-individual-files-in-c-cli-project)

I need to turn off clr support on the single .cpp file.